# Another (simple) self-referential aptitude test

Tags: logical-deduction

Nine months ago I started my journey on Puzzling in a rough way with [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99781/is-this-a-good-question-for-an-iq-test) question.

I honesty hope this time I won't generate so extended discussion...!
I love self-referential questions, puzzles or tests. And I still think those make the most efficient way to evaluate the intelligence of a person. Simply because it doesn't require any level of math knowledge or algebraic familiarity. They just rely on pure logics.

Recently I made the next test to give my students when they begin to learn logic. It's a simple one (with just five questions and three options for each one). Can you figure the answers out?

**THE TEST:**

> **QUESTION #1:** The number of questions of this test with the answer **A** is
> **A)** zero
> **B)** one
> **C)** two

> **QUESTION #2:** The maximum number of consecutive questions with the same answer is
> **A)** zero
> **B)** one
> **C)** two

> **QUESTION #3:** The answer to the question 4 is
> **A)** B
> **B)** C
> **C)** A

> **QUESTION #4:** In total, the number of questions with the same answer as this one is:
> **A)** zero
> **B)** one
> **C)** two

> **QUESTION #5:** The number of questions between this one and the last one with the same answer as this one is
> **A)** one
> **B)** two
> **C)** three

**GOOD LUCK!**

**PLEASE NOTE** that every time a question refers the answer to another question, it refers to the letter option, not to the answer itself.

**NOTE TO CLEAR THING UP:** Please be literal on your interpretation of the questions. There are some contradictions which rule out some of the answers.

Comment: A few clarifications: is Question 2 talking about pairs of answers, or does a single answer automatically set the minimum at 1 (ie is the maximum number of consecutive questions with the same answer for a sequence of ABCAB 1 or 0?). Also does question 4 count itself?

Comment: Further to StephenTG's question, with the sequence ABCAB, would the answer to question 5 be two or three?

Comment: @StephenTG, please be literal (you can exclude some options with your reasoning and that's the intended way ;) )

Comment: @hexomino, in your scenario, the answer to the question 5 would be two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without depending on other questions we can already deduce:

> Q1 cannot be A, because then the number of answers that are A would be zero
>  Q2 must be B or C, because we must have a least one consecutive question with answer X
>  Q4 cannot be A, because then none of the answer can be A. (This is, if "the number of questions with the same answer as this one" includes this question, which I think OP meant)

Then,

> because Q4 cannot be A, Q3 cannot be C
>  So:
>  Q1: .,B,C
>  Q2: .,B,C
>  Q3: A,B,.
>  Q4: .,B,C
>  Q5: A,B,C

If we assume

> **Q3 to be B**, and therefore Q4 is C, then Q1 cannot be C (only 1 answer is A) must be B (A already excluded). Therefore, Q5 must be A. Meaning:
>  Q1: .,B,.
>  Q2: .,B,C
>  Q3: .,B,.
>  Q4: .,.,C
>  Q5: A,.,.
>
>  However, since Q5 is A, there must be another question that answers A. This is not possible since we showed only one question can be A.

Therefore, our assumption is false

> and Q3 is NOT B. Q3 must therefore be A.
>  If Q3 is A, and therefore Q4 is B, then only Q4 can be B.
>  Then, Q1 must C (because no more B's allowed)
>  And Q2 is C (same reason)
>
>  Giving:
>
>  Q1: .,.,C
>  Q2: .,.,C
>  Q3: A,.,.
>  Q4: .,B,.
>  Q5: A,.,C
>
>  Then Q5 must be A, to leave gap 1 between the last A (Q3) and Q5. This would not hold for C

Giving our final answer:

> Q1: .,.,C
>  Q2: .,.,C
>  Q3: A,.,.
>  Q4: .,B,.
>  Q5: A,.,.
>
>  All statements hold (2xA, 2 consecutive same answers, Q4=B, 1xB, gap between A's is 1)

Comment: That's it. You read the questions as they are. That's the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't feel like doing logic today, so as there's no [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag, I just got an Excel spreadsheet to tell me the answer:

> 1=C, 2=C, 3=A, 4=B, 5=A

Checking:

- > 2 questions with answer A
- > 2 consecutive questions with same answer
- > Q4 answer is B
- > this is the only (one) question with answer 'B'
- > just one question between this and the last with same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> CCABA

Reason, considering the questions in order:

> Q1 cannot be A. If it was, there would be at least 1 'A'.
>  Q2 cannot be B. If it was, there would be zero consecutive answers.
>  Q3 is a different answer (label) from Q4.
>  Q4 cannot be A because Q4 has the same answer as itself.
>  Q5 ties it all together:
>  - if Q5=A then Q3=A, Q4=B, so Q2=C, and Q1=C.
>  - if Q5=B then Q2=B (contradiction with Q2$\neq$B).
>  - if Q5=C then Q1=C and Q2,3,4$\neq$C, so Q2=A, Q4=B, Q3=A (but Q2=Q3 contradicts Q2=A).

Answer (score 0):

This may make me look extremely stupid (iq-wise) but here's my guess:

> Answers: 1c. 2b. 3a. 4b. 5a.

Reasoning:

> If #3 and #5 are both A, then the answer to #1 must be C.

> If the above order is correct, then no 2 of the same letter are consecutive, so it must be B for #2.

> For 3 and 4, its only what makes any sense at all: #3 could not be B, because it would contradict the answer for #2. #3 could also not be C because by having A as the answer to number 4 would contradict my answer for #1 which states that there are 2 letter As as answers, and my answer to #2 which states that no two consecutive letters can be in a row. So thus, the answers for #3 is A, and #4 is B, which would check out, as #2 would also be B, fulfilling the requirement for #4.

> And for #5, A or C could both work in this case, as #4 is the one answer between #s 3 and 5, and there are 3 between #s 1 and 5. But for the sake of the other answers, and I know this is a bit of a stretch, my final answer for #5 is A because if the correct answer was C, it would contradict #1, making it B, and thus making the last answer of C false as well.

Comment: Probably best to add a caveat about how you are interpreting questions 2,4 and 5 (see Gareth's answer, for example).

Comment: Please, take a look at my second note. Be literal... ;)

Comment: @Pspl Oops. Just realized: 3-1=1 is not correct...):  (I forgot that there were 2 between 3 and 5 and not 1)

Comment: @JoeKerr, you got that part right. THERE is one question between questions 3 and 5 (the question number 4). However, your answer to question 4 is not correct: the question starts with the sentence "In total...".

Answer (score 0):

Q4 has two plausible interpretations. If it is asking about *other* questions with the same answer (**recent comments from OP indicate, IIUC, that this is not the intention**):

> 2A is impossible.
>  If 4A then no other A, so not 1A, so more than one A, contradiction. So not 4A.
>  (I am taking Q4 to ask for the number of *other* questions with the same answer.)
>  If 5C then 1C, so two As among 2,3,4 but 2A and 4A are impossible. So not 5C.
>  If 5A then 3A so 4B. Also 5A,3A => 1C so we have C-ABA. 4B means two B answers,
>  so must be CBABA.
>  Otherwise, 5B so 2B. So no two consecutive equal answers, which means no other B.
>  We already know not 4A, so 4C, so we have -B-CB which means two other Cs, which is
>  impossible because no two consecutive equal answers.
>  So the only possibility is **CBABA**.

On the other hand, if Q4 is asking for the number of such questions *including Q4* (**which I think is what's intended**), the reasoning is very similar but not quite the same:

> 2A and 4A are obviously impossible.
>  If 5C then 1C, so two As among 2,3,4 but 2A and 4A are impossible. So not 5C.
>  If 5A then 3A so 4B so no other B, so 2C. We now have -CABA and then we must have CCABA.
>  Otherwise 5B so 2B. So no two consecutive equal answers, which means no other B.
>  We already know not 4A, so 4C and therefore 3B, so we have -BBCB which is impossible
>  because no two consecutive equal answers.
>  So the only possibility is **CCABA**.

To summarize these jointly:

> 1,3,4,5 are C,A,B,A. 2 is B if Q4 *excludes* itself and C if Q4 *includes* itself.

Comment: I would say Q2 and Q5 also have more than one interpretation (see comments).

Comment: You might be right. I don't fancy doing the analysis _eight_ times :-).

Comment: Okay, Pspl has at least clarified that your interpretation of Q5 is consistent.

Comment: Question 4 starts with the words...